# please guide to implement in website the following pop up messages to halt user action temporary

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

being used, c# asp.net css

- are you sure you want to nevigate away from this page? all changes will be lost! yes no
- do you really want to delete this?

possible conditions
  - when user clicks the cross to close the tab of browser.
  - when user clicks any link and has not saved the changes done on the lets say string in textbox

### for delete

- when user clicks delete button.

yes javascript

but i have limited time and its difficult to go through all the codes out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how pretty you want it ;p a `window.alert` or `window.confirm` provide basic clientside functionality for notifying/asking the user:

```
alert('hey there');

if(confirm('end universe - are you sure?')) {
    universe.Destroy();
}
```

For more complex scenarios you'll want to look at DHTML (usually via a library like jQuery) to create a popup window, masking the background to give the *illusion* of modality.

Note that handling *exit* is slightly different; you can subscribe to the `beforeunload` event in the browser, and return a string that is the message; for example (here using jQuery):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    if(someUnsavedChanges) return "You will lose work!!!";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2004/03/16/178.aspx)'s a quick sample I found for the confirmed delete.  There are also a number of libraries out there with out-of-the-box controls that will do such things.

As for the confirmation when leaving the page, there seem to be [a handful of approaches](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+confirm+leave+page+asp.net).  Certain browsers and/or certain settings within browsers may prevent this from working 100% of the time, though.  (Sometimes users don't want to be "locked" onto a page with JavaScript.)  But such is the nature of client-side code.